# Pruebas unitarias de interceptores en para $resource en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estoy intentando hacer test unitarios de mi aplicación en AngularJS. Estoy creando un `factory` del que heredan otros servicios para comunicarme con la base de datos haciendo uso de `$resource` y `$cacheFactory` para reducir el número de llamadas al servidor.

El `factory` en cuestión configura un interceptor para ciertas llamadas a `$resource`de forma que la cache queda invalidada al hacer estas llamadas. Este es el código:

```
ModelFactory.$inject = ['$resource', '$cacheFactory'];
function ModelFactory($resource, $cacheFactory){
    return function (baseUrl, paramDefaults, actions, options) {
        var cache = $cacheFactory(baseUrl);
        var params = angular.extend({id: '@id'}, paramDefaults);
        var interceptor = { response: invalidateCache };

        actions = angular.extend({}, actions, {
            'get':      { method: 'GET' },
            'query':    { method: 'GET', cache: cache, isArray: true },
            'save':     { method: 'POST', interceptor: interceptor },
            'update':   { method: 'PUT', interceptor: interceptor},
            'remove':   { method: 'DELETE', interceptor: interceptor },
            'delete':   { method: 'DELETE', interceptor: interceptor }
        });

        var model = $resource(baseUrl + '/:id', params, actions, options);
        model.invalidateCache = invalidateCache;


        /**
         * Invalida la cache eliminando todos los registros
         */
        function invalidateCache() {
            cache.removeAll();
        }

        return model;
    };
}
```

Al realizar las pruebas utilizando `karma`y `jasmine`, creo un espía para la función `model.invalidateCache()` para comprobar que se llama cuando corresponde. Este es el código del `spec`:

```
describe("Cached resource factory", function () {

    var server;
    var factory;

    beforeEach(module('intranet'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend, Model) {
        server = $httpBackend;
        factory = Model;

        hlpHttpBackend.setCommonIntranetCalls($httpBackend)
    }));


    // ...

    it("should invalidate the cache with every successfull call to create, update or delete action", function () {

        var itemInfo = {field1: 'one', field2: 'two'};
        var dbItemInfo = {id: 1, field1: 'one', field2: 'two'};
        var modItemInfo = {id: 1, field1: 'one', field2: 'modified-two'};
        var resource = new factory('/data');

        spyOn(resource, 'invalidateCache').and.callThrough();

        // Create
        server.expectPOST('/data').respond(dbItemInfo);
        var item = resource.save(itemInfo);
        server.flush();


        // Update
       server.expectPUT('/data/' + item.id).respond(modItemInfo);
       item.field2 = 'modified-two';
       item.$update();
       server.flush();

       // DELETE
       server.expectDELETE('/data/' + item.id).respond(null);
       item.$delete();
       server.flush();

       // cachedResource debe haber invalidado la cache 3 veces, una por cada llamada
       // a create, update y delete
       expect(resource.invalidateCache).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    });
});
```

El código del `factory` funciona correctamente, es decir, sí se están haciendo las llamadas al interceptor, pero el teste falla:

> ```
> Expected spy invalidateCache to have been called 3 times. It was called 0 times.
> ```

¿Alguna idea? Quizá no debería estar haciendo testing de esto, al fin y al cabo, es el código de `$resource` y no el mío el que se encarga de llamar al interceptor.